# Oblique direction for shots in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am creating a 3D Game in unity where you are a Space ship shooting projectiles, I want to make it so when I pick up an powerUp to change the style of shooting, and for that I created another 2 bullets with different scripts for the bullet that should go oblique on the left side and the one that should go oblique right.
I created a prefab of those two and when I shoot they are not moving oblique but only on the x axis.

If I have only one bullet it is working, but when I add the second one is moving just on the x axis not both x and y.

This is the code for both the bullet that is working and go oblique on the right side and for those two that are not working:

```
public class laser_Right : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int speed = 8;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Movelaser();
    }

    void Movelaser()
    {
        Vector3 movement = (Vector3.up + Vector3.right).normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;


        transform.Translate(movement);

        if (transform.position.y >= 9)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

}
```

For the left bullet is the same, but different direction.

I am pretty sure the code is correct but something else is the problem, maybe because I created a prefab out of two bullets?
The bullets have asigned different script, so I don't understand why it would not work.

Comment: Maybe also show the script that *is* working?

Comment: @Wyck The code I wrote  above is the code that is working when I have only one bullet and when I have two of them is not working as it should .

Comment: It's quite important how do you set your vector 'movement' in unworking script. Do you just use '-Vector3.right' or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script moves the projectile in the absolute global direction of `Vector3.up + Vector3.right`.  It's not clear whether you've oriented your projectile objects to face forward in the direction of their intended motion or not, but you probably *should* do that. Then you can use `transform.forward` to get a vector in the direction of what is locally "forward" relative to the object to which the script is applied.

Something like:

```
Vector3 movement = transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;
```

Just be sure to create your 3 objects so that each one is oriented to face in the direction you want it to travel.

#### alternatively...

**If you don't want to reorient the objects**, you could add in a a *lateral* component to its motion with `transform.right`.  This seems to be in line with your original approach.

```
Vector3 movement = (transform.forward + transform.right).normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;
```

This will make it move diagonally in the direction that is 45° right of its local forward.

But it's probably best to just rotate your object to face in the appropriate direction when you create it, and use the code my first example.

Comment: this is useful, thank you!
As projectiles they are rotated 45* but they are simple 3D capsule objects unity offer and they are facing the z axis, is there a way I can change the direction they are facing without rotating in a weird way?
Using the first code the projectile would go on the Z axis and the second one is working a bit better, on the z axis but oblique.

Thank you!

Comment: The approaches are usually: 1) Create a "projectile spawner" that is relative to the "gun" -- you could have 3 such spawners, each manually set to the angles you like  Create projectiles with the transform of the spawner from which they were emitted.  2) Orient each newly created projectile object relative to the gun's orientation. Then you can create a "planar fan" of some _arbitrary number_ of n spread-out projectiles by rotating each one about its local up vector.